# Concatenate multiple rows in one fields

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have 2 tables as following

```
Table1
Id       TagNo        FBay      FPanel      TBay     TPanel
------------------------------------------------------------
 1        10000        A1         A2         E4        F2
 2        10001        A2         R2         F2        Q1


Table2
 Id      TagNo    CNo     FDevice
-----------------------------
  1       10000    1       X101
  2       10000    2       XF09
  3       10000    3       X101
  4       10000    4       XY
  5       10001    1       X20
  6       10002    2       X20
  7       10003    3       X20
```

I want to have this result

```
  TagNo        FBay      FPanel      TBay     TPanel       FDevice
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
   10000        A1         A2         E4        F2       X101,XF09,XY
   10001        A2         R2         F2        Q1       X20
```

The numbers of records are too much so if I want to use Stuff Tsql it takes arounf 7 minutes to have a result back from database which is not so good. so is there any solution to have this result?

this is the part of the query which i used stuff in it

```
SELECT Distinct TagNo, FDevice = STUFF((SELECT ',' + FDevice FROM Table2 i
                      WHERE
                      i.TagNo = o.TagNo AND
                      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
                      FROM Table2 o
                      GROUP BY TagNo
```

Comment: Please post your STUFF query for us as a starting point? Also, at what sort of record count are you actually looking?

Comment: Are you looking for SQL **or** LINQ query?

Comment: the sql  is much more better for my aim , but i am curious about two ways to know. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no any kind of **Stuff()** function in LINQ. But may be you can achieve the same using this

```
var results = from rw in Table2
            group rw.FDevice by new { rw.TagNo } into grp
            select new { grp.Key.TagNo, FDevice = string.Join (", ", grp) };
```

**Note:** I have not tested it into VS, so there might be any syntax error. Please comment if any, Thanks.